# My website won't load on the Google Chrome browser on Android devices

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

I have recently added a few new features on a website (a gallery viewer using [glightbox](https://biati-digital.github.io/glightbox/) and a toggle navbar button). The website with all its features works fine on computers and Apple devices and on some browsers on Android, but it doesn't work on the Google Chrome browser and throws the *[Aw, Snap!](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid#zippy=%2Cpage-loading-error-codes-and-issues)* error at me.

I have now tried to remove the features and turn the page right back to a version with no javascript, because that was the first thing to come to my mind that could cause problems. The error still persists.

Does anybody know how to fix this? Or, does anybody have the same problem?

website: [astropi-hackathon.org](https://astropi-hackathon.org/)

git: [astropi-hackathon-website](https://github.com/pgersl/astropi-hackathon-website)

NEWS:
I've tried to delete all the javascript from the site but that didn't really work. I also tried to remove all photos froom the site and it suddenly does work. My thought was that the size of these photos was the issue, but by reducing it, nothing changed and the site still woon't load on phones. Could the problem be elsewhere?

Comment: in my phone i got aw snap first time then if i refresh it loads the page

Comment: Is the current live version have everything enabled? The mobile menu doesn't work in any browser for me, because the JS resource doesn't exist (404).